# Not able to deploy PubSub function in firebase cloud functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin, google-cloud-scheduler

I was trying to deploy a PubSub function:

```
exports.sendReminder 
    = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 6 * * *').timeZone('Asia/Kolkata').onRun((context) => {
        console.log('Wake up! It\'s 6AM');
        return null;
    }
);
```

1. Cloud schedular API was disabled before I tried to deploy the function for the first time.
2. It got enabled automatically.
3. PubSub is also enabled.

#### Expected behavior

Since Cloud Scheduler API and PubSub have enabled for the project. ideally, there should not be any error while deploying the function. The error does mention trying after a few minutes. But it's been 24 hrs since I enabled the PubSub and Cloud Scheduler API.

#### Actual behavior

```
> eslint .

+  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (41.54 KB) for uploading
+  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: uploading functions in project: sendReminder(us-central1)
i  functions: creating Node.js 8 function sendReminder(us-central1)...
i  scheduler: ensuring required API cloudscheduler.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  pubsub: ensuring required API pubsub.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  scheduler: required API cloudscheduler.googleapis.com is enabled
+  pubsub: required API pubsub.googleapis.com is enabled

Error: HTTP Error: 403, Cloud Scheduler API has not been used in the project before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/cloudscheduler.googleapis.com/overview then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
```

#### Version info

node: v12.10.0

firebase-functions: 8.2.0

firebase-tools: 8.2.0

firebase-admin: 8.2.0

Comment: If the Firebase CLI isn't working the way you expect, contact Firebase support for assistance.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: I've added an issue. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/691

Answer (score 3):

It finally worked. It was strange because I have enabled all the APIs necessary. The possible reasons for it were not working is that I initialized deployment during the outage and some permissions failed. So, it was being denied due to the permissions.

I was in touch with the firebase team for the last few days. We tried different things. Steps I followed to solve this issue as instructed by Firebase support:

1. Disabled already enabled Schedular API and enabled it again in the console: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/cloudscheduler.googleapis.com
2. Created a dummy cron job by using the console: https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/quickstart#create_a_job
3. Deployed the function using Firebase CLI and it worked.

Comment: I tried this without success, though I didn't have the same issue, mine just seems to say everything is good, and then at the last minute fails to deploy